# Using htmlunit try to login in a website, facing this kind error

Tags: java, htmlunit

#### Code

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package qzone;

import java.net.*;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.FailingHttpStatusCodeException;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

/**
 *
 * @author wangyi
 */
public class Main {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main main = new Main();
        try {
            main.submittingForm();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    public void submittingForm() throws Exception {
        final WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
        //webClient.setJavaScriptEnabled(false);
        // Get the first page
        final HtmlPage page1 = webClient.getPage("http://qzone.qq.com/");

        // Get the form that we are dealing with and within that form,
        // find the submit button and the field that we want to change.
        final HtmlForm form = page1.getFormByName("loginform");

        //final HtmlSubmitInput button = form.getInputByName("subbtn");
        final HtmlSubmitInput button = page1.getHtmlElementById("subbtn");
        final HtmlTextInput loginName = form.getInputByName("u");
        final HtmlPasswordInput loginPs = form.getInputByName("p");

        // Change the value of the text field
        loginName.setValueAttribute("525356734");
        loginPs.setValueAttribute("5230911,..");


        // Now submit the form by clicking the button and get back the second page.
        final HtmlPage page2 = button.click();
        final String pageAsXml = page2.asText();
        System.out.println(pageAsXml);
        //webClient.closeAllWindows();
    }

    public void homePage() throws Exception {
    final WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
    final HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage("http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net");
    //massertEquals("HtmlUnit - Welcome to HtmlUnit", page.getTitleText());

    final String pageAsXml = page.asXml();
    //assertTrue(pageAsXml.contains("<body class=\"composite\">"));

    final String pageAsText = page.asText();
    //assertTrue(pageAsText.contains("Support for the HTTP and HTTPS protocols"));
    //System.out.println(pageAsText);
    webClient.closeAllWindows();
}
}
```

#### Log

```
Dec 23, 2010 9:05:31 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.IncorrectnessListenerImpl notify
WARNING: Expected content type of 'application/javascript' or 'application/ecmascript' for remotely loaded JavaScript element at 'http://imgcache.qq.com/ptlogin/ac/v7/js/login_div.js?v=1.2.1', but got 'application/x-javascript'.
Dec 23, 2010 9:05:31 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.ActiveXObject jsConstructor
WARNING: Automation server can't create object for SSOAxCtrlForPTLogin.SSOForPTLogin2
Dec 23, 2010 9:05:31 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.StrictErrorReporter runtimeError
SEVERE: runtimeError: message=[Automation server can't create object] sourceName=[http://imgcache.qq.com/ptlogin/ac/v7/js/login_div.js?v=1.2.1] line=[1] lineSource=[null] lineOffset=[0]
Dec 23, 2010 9:05:31 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript isExecutionNeeded
WARNING: Script is not JavaScript (type: text/html, language: ). Skipping execution.
Dec 23, 2010 9:05:31 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript isExecutionNeeded
WARNING: Script is not JavaScript (type: text/html, language: ). Skipping execution.
Dec 23, 2010 9:05:32 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.IncorrectnessListenerImpl notify
WARNING: Expected content type of 'application/javascript' or 'application/ecmascript' for remotely loaded JavaScript element at 'http://ptlogin2.qq.com/check?uin=525356734&appid=15000101&r=0.052038031951785135', but got 'application/x-javascript'.
Dec 23, 2010 9:05:33 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.IncorrectnessListenerImpl notify
WARNING: Expected content type of 'application/javascript' or 'application/ecmascript' for remotely loaded JavaScript element at 'http://ptlogin2.qq.com/login?u=525356734&p=3DEA711A779CD7F24D771D1E568D5A94&verifycode=!NU7&=on&aid=15000101&u1=http%3A%2F%2Fimgcache.qq.com%2Fqzone%2Fv5%2Floginsucc.html%3Fpara%3Dizone&ptredirect=1&h=1&from_ui=1&dumy=&fp=loginerroralert', but got 'application/x-javascript'.
Dec 23, 2010 9:05:33 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.IncorrectnessListenerImpl notify
WARNING: Expected content type of 'application/javascript' or 'application/ecmascript' for remotely loaded JavaScript element at 'http://imgcache.qq.com/ac/qzfl/appclientlib.js', but got 'application/x-javascript'.
Dec 23, 2010 9:05:35 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.IncorrectnessListenerImpl notify
WARNING: Expected content type of 'application/javascript' or 'application/ecmascript' for remotely loaded JavaScript element at 'http://cnc.qzs.qq.com/ac/qzone/qzfl/qzfl_2.0.9.0.js', but got 'application/x-javascript'.
Dec 23, 2010 9:05:37 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.html.HTMLDocument jsxFunction_getElementById
WARNING: getElementById(script1293109537081) did a getElementByName for Internet Explorer
Dec 23, 2010 9:05:37 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.IncorrectnessListenerImpl notify
WARNING: Expected content type of 'application/javascript' or 'application/ecmascript' for remotely loaded JavaScript element at 'http://cnc.qzonestyle.gtimg.cn/ac/qzone/v5/G/common/global/global_B419b419_b.js', but got 'application/x-javascript'.
Dec 23, 2010 9:05:38 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.IncorrectnessListenerImpl notify
WARNING: Expected content type of 'application/javascript' or 'application/ecmascript' for remotely loaded JavaScript element at 'http://cnc.qzonestyle.gtimg.cn/ac/qzone/v5/G/common/interface/interface_B419b419_b.js', but got 'application/x-javascript'.
Dec 23, 2010 9:05:38 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.IncorrectnessListenerImpl notify
WARNING: Expected content type of 'application/javascript' or 'application/ecmascript' for remotely loaded JavaScript element at 'http://cnc.qzonestyle.gtimg.cn/ac/qzone/v5/G/common/shop/shop_B206b207.js', but got 'application/x-javascript'.
Dec 23, 2010 9:05:39 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.IncorrectnessListenerImpl notify
WARNING: Expected content type of 'application/javascript' or 'application/ecmascript' for remotely loaded JavaScript element at 'http://cnc.qzonestyle.gtimg.cn/ac/qzone/v5/ofp/ofp_B206b207.js', but got 'application/x-javascript'.
Dec 23, 2010 9:05:39 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.IncorrectnessListenerImpl notify
WARNING: Expected content type of 'application/javascript' or 'application/ecmascript' for remotely loaded JavaScript element at 'http://cnc.qzonestyle.gtimg.cn/qzone/v5/statistic.js', but got 'application/x-javascript'.
Dec 23, 2010 9:05:40 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.html.HTMLDocument jsxFunction_getElementById
WARNING: getElementById(script1293109540568) did a getElementByName for Internet Explorer
Dec 23, 2010 9:05:40 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.IncorrectnessListenerImpl notify
WARNING: Expected content type of 'application/javascript' or 'application/ecmascript' for remotely loaded JavaScript element at 'http://cnc.qzs.qq.com/ac/qzfl/appclientlib.js', but got 'application/x-javascript'.
Dec 23, 2010 9:05:40 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.IncorrectnessListenerImpl notify
WARNING: Expected content type of 'application/javascript' or 'application/ecmascript' for remotely loaded JavaScript element at 'http://cnc.qzonestyle.gtimg.cn/qzone/v5/owner2/ic/IC_Core_v2.0.js', but got 'application/x-javascript'.
Dec 23, 2010 9:05:41 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.IncorrectnessListenerImpl notify
WARNING: Expected content type of 'application/javascript' or 'application/ecmascript' for remotely loaded JavaScript element at 'http://cnc.qzonestyle.gtimg.cn/qzone/v5/owner2/ic/IC_Extend_v2.0.js', but got 'application/x-javascript'.
Dec 23, 2010 9:05:41 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.IncorrectnessListenerImpl notify
WARNING: Expected content type of 'application/javascript' or 'application/ecmascript' for remotely loaded JavaScript element at 'http://cnc.qzonestyle.gtimg.cn/qzone/v5/owner2/ic/ic_trigger_ex.js', but got 'application/x-javascript'.
Dec 23, 2010 9:05:42 PM qzone.Main main
```

### Exception

```
SEVERE: null
net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.WrappedException: Wrapped com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.ScriptException: Wrapped com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.ScriptException: TypeError: Cannot find function createElement in object [object]. (http://cnc.qzs.qq.com/ac/qzone/qzfl/qzfl_2.0.9.0.js#331)
        at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Context.throwAsScriptRuntimeEx(Context.java:1797)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.doProcessPostponedActions(JavaScriptEngine.java:649)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.processPostponedActions(JavaScriptEngine.java:705)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlElement.click(HtmlElement.java:1265)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlElement.click(HtmlElement.java:1214)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlElement.click(HtmlElement.java:1177)
        at qzone.Main.submittingForm(Main.java:54)
        at qzone.Main.main(Main.java:27)
Caused by: com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.ScriptException: Wrapped com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.ScriptException: TypeError: Cannot find function createElement in object [object]. (http://cnc.qzs.qq.com/ac/qzone/qzfl/qzfl_2.0.9.0.js#331)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$HtmlUnitContextAction.run(JavaScriptEngine.java:601)
        at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Context.call(Context.java:537)
        at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory.call(ContextFactory.java:538)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.execute(JavaScriptEngine.java:499)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage.loadExternalJavaScriptFile(HtmlPage.java:970)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript.executeScriptIfNeeded(HtmlScript.java:363)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript$1.execute(HtmlScript.java:225)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.doProcessPostponedActions(JavaScriptEngine.java:644)
        ... 6 more
Caused by: com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.ScriptException: Wrapped com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.ScriptException: TypeError: Cannot find function createElement in object [object]. (http://cnc.qzs.qq.com/ac/qzone/qzfl/qzfl_2.0.9.0.js#331)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$HtmlUnitContextAction.run(JavaScriptEngine.java:601)
        at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Context.call(Context.java:537)
        at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory.call(ContextFactory.java:538)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.execute(JavaScriptEngine.java:499)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.execute(JavaScriptEngine.java:474)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage.executeJavaScriptIfPossible(HtmlPage.java:880)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript.executeInlineScriptIfNeeded(HtmlScript.java:312)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript.executeScriptIfNeeded(HtmlScript.java:379)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript$1.execute(HtmlScript.java:225)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript.onAllChildrenAddedToPage(HtmlScript.java:245)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser$HtmlUnitDOMBuilder.endElement(HTMLParser.java:578)
        at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endElement(Unknown Source)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser$HtmlUnitDOMBuilder.endElement(HTMLParser.java:536)
        at org.cyberneko.html.HTMLTagBalancer.callEndElement(HTMLTagBalancer.java:1136)
        at org.cyberneko.html.HTMLTagBalancer.endElement(HTMLTagBalancer.java:1038)
        at org.cyberneko.html.filters.DefaultFilter.endElement(DefaultFilter.java:206)
        at org.cyberneko.html.filters.NamespaceBinder.endElement(NamespaceBinder.java:329)
        at org.cyberneko.html.HTMLScanner$ContentScanner.scanEndElement(HTMLScanner.java:2999)
        at org.cyberneko.html.HTMLScanner$ContentScanner.scan(HTMLScanner.java:1991)
        at org.cyberneko.html.HTMLScanner.scanDocument(HTMLScanner.java:895)
        at org.cyberneko.html.HTMLConfiguration.parse(HTMLConfiguration.java:499)
        at org.cyberneko.html.HTMLConfiguration.parse(HTMLConfiguration.java:452)
        at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser$HtmlUnitDOMBuilder.parse(HTMLParser.java:765)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser.parse(HTMLParser.java:211)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser.parseHtml(HTMLParser.java:165)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultPageCreator.createHtmlPage(DefaultPageCreator.java:225)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultPageCreator.createPage(DefaultPageCreator.java:108)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.loadWebResponseInto(WebClient.java:429)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.loadDownloadedResponses(WebClient.java:2127)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.doProcessPostponedActions(JavaScriptEngine.java:627)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.access$400(JavaScriptEngine.java:78)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$HtmlUnitContextAction.run(JavaScriptEngine.java:596)
        ... 13 more
Caused by: com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.ScriptException: Wrapped com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.ScriptException: TypeError: Cannot find function createElement in object [object]. (http://cnc.qzs.qq.com/ac/qzone/qzfl/qzfl_2.0.9.0.js#331)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$HtmlUnitContextAction.run(JavaScriptEngine.java:601)
        at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Context.call(Context.java:537)
        at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory.call(ContextFactory.java:538)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.execute(JavaScriptEngine.java:499)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.execute(JavaScriptEngine.java:474)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage.executeJavaScriptIfPossible(HtmlPage.java:880)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript.executeInlineScriptIfNeeded(HtmlScript.java:312)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript.executeScriptIfNeeded(HtmlScript.java:379)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript$1.execute(HtmlScript.java:225)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript.onAllChildrenAddedToPage(HtmlScript.java:245)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser$HtmlUnitDOMBuilder.endElement(HTMLParser.java:578)
        at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endElement(Unknown Source)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser$HtmlUnitDOMBuilder.endElement(HTMLParser.java:536)
        at org.cyberneko.html.HTMLTagBalancer.callEndElement(HTMLTagBalancer.java:1136)
        at org.cyberneko.html.HTMLTagBalancer.endElement(HTMLTagBalancer.java:1038)
        at org.cyberneko.html.filters.DefaultFilter.endElement(DefaultFilter.java:206)
        at org.cyberneko.html.filters.NamespaceBinder.endElement(NamespaceBinder.java:329)
        at org.cyberneko.html.HTMLScanner$ContentScanner.scanEndElement(HTMLScanner.java:2999)
        at org.cyberneko.html.HTMLScanner$ContentScanner.scan(HTMLScanner.java:1991)
        at org.cyberneko.html.HTMLScanner.scanDocument(HTMLScanner.java:895)
        at org.cyberneko.html.HTMLConfiguration.parse(HTMLConfiguration.java:499)
        at org.cyberneko.html.HTMLConfiguration.parse(HTMLConfiguration.java:452)
        at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser$HtmlUnitDOMBuilder.parse(HTMLParser.java:765)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser.parse(HTMLParser.java:211)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser.parseHtml(HTMLParser.java:165)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultPageCreator.createHtmlPage(DefaultPageCreator.java:225)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultPageCreator.createPage(DefaultPageCreator.java:108)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.loadWebResponseInto(WebClient.java:429)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:307)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.BaseFrame.loadInnerPageIfPossible(BaseFrame.java:141)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.BaseFrame.loadInnerPage(BaseFrame.java:100)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage.loadFrames(HtmlPage.java:1763)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage.initialize(HtmlPage.java:204)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.loadWebResponseInto(WebClient.java:436)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.loadDownloadedResponses(WebClient.java:2127)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.doProcessPostponedActions(JavaScriptEngine.java:627)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.access$400(JavaScriptEngine.java:78)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$HtmlUnitContextAction.run(JavaScriptEngine.java:596)
        ... 45 more
Caused by: net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.WrappedException: Wrapped com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.ScriptException: TypeError: Cannot find function createElement in object [object]. (http://cnc.qzs.qq.com/ac/qzone/qzfl/qzfl_2.0.9.0.js#331)
        at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Context.throwAsScriptRuntimeEx(Context.java:1797)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.doProcessPostponedActions(JavaScriptEngine.java:649)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.access$400(JavaScriptEngine.java:78)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$HtmlUnitContextAction.run(JavaScriptEngine.java:596)
        ... 83 more
Caused by: com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.ScriptException: TypeError: Cannot find function createElement in object [object]. (http://cnc.qzs.qq.com/ac/qzone/qzfl/qzfl_2.0.9.0.js#331)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$HtmlUnitContextAction.run(JavaScriptEngine.java:601)
        at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Context.call(Context.java:537)
        at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory.call(ContextFactory.java:538)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.execute(JavaScriptEngine.java:499)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage.loadExternalJavaScriptFile(HtmlPage.java:970)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript.executeScriptIfNeeded(HtmlScript.java:363)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript$1.execute(HtmlScript.java:225)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.doProcessPostponedActions(JavaScriptEngine.java:644)
        ... 85 more
Caused by: net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.EcmaError: TypeError: Cannot find function createElement in object [object]. (http://cnc.qzs.qq.com/ac/qzone/qzfl/qzfl_2.0.9.0.js#331)
        at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:3772)
        at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:3750)
        at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.typeError(ScriptRuntime.java:3778)
        at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.typeError2(ScriptRuntime.java:3797)
        at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.notFunctionError(ScriptRuntime.java:3861)
        at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.getPropFunctionAndThisHelper(ScriptRuntime.java:2346)
        at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.getPropFunctionAndThis(ScriptRuntime.java:2313)
        at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Interpreter.interpretLoop(Interpreter.java:1515)
        at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Interpreter.interpret(Interpreter.java:845)
        at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.InterpretedFunction.call(InterpretedFunction.java:164)
        at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:429)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.HtmlUnitContextFactory.doTopCall(HtmlUnitContextFactory.java:269)
        at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3162)
        at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.InterpretedFunction.exec(InterpretedFunction.java:175)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$3.doRun(JavaScriptEngine.java:490)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$HtmlUnitContextAction.run(JavaScriptEngine.java:595)
        ... 92 more
BUILD SUCCESSFUL
```

Comment: I think its useful to provide some code too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't really call this an answer but assuming the problem is Javascript detection and management in HTMLUnit

1) htmlunit is open source, so you should be able to configure it to accept application/x-javascript as JavaScript

2) if you control the server, the mime type is configured by the server there and you may find it easier to make the change on the server.

Answer (score 4):

Just use `webclient.setJavaScriptEnabled(false);`

It worked for me hope it helps you.sorry for delaying the answer.

Comment: No longer works as of version 2.26. It should now read `webclient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(false);`

Answer (score -1):

I was receiving error similar to this,then i changed the browser version it helped.So just try different browser versions